# How to fix "The seed entity for entity type 'MenuFoodItem' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'FoodItemId1'."?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, entity-framework

I am developing a Web App and Service that specialises in catering events with menu's and bookings. I am in the process of building a Database with seed data, however I am getting an error when I try to make an initial create.

The error being:

> The seed entity for entity type 'MenuFoodItem' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'FoodItemId1'.

My code is in C# and is split across 5 classes:

FoodBooking, FoodItem, Menu, MenuFoodItem and CateringDbContext.

Here is my code for each class:

CateringDbContexct:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class CateringDbContext : DbContext
    {
        // Notes
        // - DbSet defines the database table.
        // - the class name is defined as part of the data model
        // - the instance/object name is normally plural
        // - by default, the instance name will become the table name

        public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FoodItem> FoodItems { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MenuFoodItem> MenuFoodItems { get; set; }

        public DbSet<FoodBooking> FoodBookings { get; set; }

        private string DbPath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        // Constructor to set-up the database path & name
        public CateringDbContext()
        {
            var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments;
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
            DbPath = Path.Join(path, "ThAmCo.Catering.db");
        }
        // OnConfiguring to specify that the SQLite database engine will be used
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);


            builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>()
                .HasKey(ms => new { ms.MenuId, ms.FoodItemId });


            builder.Entity<Menu>()
                .HasMany(m => m.MenuFoodItems)
                .WithOne(fi => fi.Menu)
                .HasForeignKey(tr => tr.FoodItemId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.Entity<FoodItem>()
                .HasMany(m => m.MenuFoodItems)
                .WithOne(fi => fi.FoodItem)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);


            // Seed/Test data to be added here

            builder.Entity<Menu>().HasData(
                new Menu { MenuId = 1, MenuName = "Pasta" },
                new Menu { MenuId = 2, MenuName = "Pizza" },
                new Menu { MenuId = 3, MenuName = "Pies" },
                new Menu { MenuId = 4, MenuName = "Carvery" },
                new Menu { MenuId = 5, MenuName = "Desert" }
                );

            builder.Entity<FoodItem>().HasData(
                new FoodItem { FoodItemId = 1, Description = "Tuna Pasta Bake", UnitPrice = 9.99F },
                new FoodItem { FoodItemId = 2, Description = "Four Cheese Pizza", UnitPrice = 10.99F },
                new FoodItem { FoodItemId = 3, Description = "Chicken and Leak Pie", UnitPrice = 5.65F },
                new FoodItem { FoodItemId = 4, Description = "Usual Sunday Carvery", UnitPrice = 12.99F },
                new FoodItem { FoodItemId = 5, Description = "Ice Cream with melted Cookies", UnitPrice = 6.99F }
                );

            builder.Entity<MenuFoodItem>().HasData(
                new MenuFoodItem { MenuId = 1, FoodItemId = 1 },
                new MenuFoodItem { MenuId = 2, FoodItemId = 2 },
                new MenuFoodItem { MenuId = 3, FoodItemId = 3 },
                new MenuFoodItem { MenuId = 4, FoodItemId = 4 },
                new MenuFoodItem { MenuId = 5, FoodItemId = 5 }
                );

            builder.Entity<FoodBooking>().HasData(
                new FoodBooking { FoodBookingId = 1, ClientReferenceId = 1, NumberOfGuests = 1, MenuId = 1 },
                new FoodBooking { FoodBookingId = 2, ClientReferenceId = 2, NumberOfGuests = 2, MenuId = 2 },
                new FoodBooking { FoodBookingId = 3, ClientReferenceId = 3, NumberOfGuests = 3, MenuId = 3 },
                new FoodBooking { FoodBookingId = 4, ClientReferenceId = 4, NumberOfGuests = 4, MenuId = 4 },
                new FoodBooking { FoodBookingId = 5, ClientReferenceId = 5, NumberOfGuests = 5, MenuId = 5 }
              );


        }

    }
}
```

FoodBooking:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class FoodBooking
    {
        [Required]
        public int FoodBookingId { get; set; }

        public int ClientReferenceId { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfGuests { get; set; }

        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        //Placeholder for link to FoodItem
        public FoodItem? FoodItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

FoodItem:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class FoodItem
    {
        [Key]

        public int FoodItemId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;

        public float UnitPrice { get; set; }

        // Placeholder for List of MenuFoodItem
        public List<MenuFoodItem> MenuFoodItems { get; set; }
       
        // Placeholder for List of FoodBooking
        public List<FoodBooking> FoodBookings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Menu:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class Menu
    {
        [Key]


        [MaxLength(15)]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string MenuName { get; set; } = null!;



        //Placeholder for List of MenuFoodItem
        public List<MenuFoodItem> MenuFoodItems { get; set; }


    }
}
```

MenuFoodItem:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class MenuFoodItem
    {
        [Required]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public int FoodItemId { get; set; } 

        //Placeholder for link to FoodItem
        public FoodItem? FoodItem { get; set; }

        //Placeholder for link to Menu
        public Menu? Menu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I believe I'm going wrong somewhere with my relationships, but not 100% sure which part.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This line `.HasForeignKey(tr => tr.FoodItemId)` is wrong. It should be `MenuId`.

Comment: Ahhhh yes, I see - thank you kindly for pointing that out, that fixed that
I'm stilling going slightly however as the FoodItemId shows up null on the FoodBooking table, I do not want it there. 

How would I go about solving that?

Comment: `FoodItem?` is nullable. Also, should that `MenuId` be there (in `FoodBooking`)? Anyway, EF implements nullable reference types (NRT) when NRT is enabled, which is confusing sometimes, because now it's more than merely the compiler feature it was intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the use of `[MaxLength(15)]` for the `FoodItemId` property, which is supposed to represent an integer value and not a string. This could lead to a conflict and explains the error message.
see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.stringvalidatorattribute.maxlength?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class MenuFoodItem
    {
        [Required]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int FoodItemId { get; set; }

        public FoodItem? FoodItem { get; set; }

        public Menu? Menu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You should do the same for the Menu class.

```
namespace ThAmCo.Catering.Data
{
    public class Menu
    {
        [Key]


        public int MenuId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string MenuName { get; set; } = null!;



        //Placeholder for List of MenuFoodItem
        public List<MenuFoodItem> MenuFoodItems { get; set; }


    }
}
```

If you actually wanted to use the max value what is valid for integers, you can use the `[MaxValue()]` attribute instead for your integers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.integervalidatorattribute.maxvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0